# What does this mqtt-connection module used for?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

What does this mqtt-connection module in nodejs used for? Does it means with this mqtt-connection then we do not need any broker?
[mqtt-connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-connection#installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed create a new server listening on MQTT and connect to it using the client version.

For exemple you can run an express app with the following architecture

```
-server
   - server.js //Start your server here
-app
   - your client views and controllers go here
```

However, if you are planning to setup a big application, I strongly recommend you to use brokers such as Mosquito or ActiveMQ.